# pandas datetimeindex asfreq not working together?

Tags: datetime, dataframe

This sample code is an attempt to mimic a Pandas DataFrame coming from sqlalchemy and a mysql/mariadb database. When attempting to get just float and integer data from that database via the dataframe, I can succesfully use df.asfreq to refer to one column and get np.nan/NaN for the other column, and then I can make interpolate or polynomes to fill in data. However this seems not possible with a timeseries of "datetime" (generic term) like "2005-09-29 15:27:00" type.

Have tested with ".astype('datetime64[ns]')" and "to_datetime".

What I have is data around one or more missing "datetimes" (here in the form of ['recdate'] column and I want the ['outdoortemperature'] column to be filled in with NaN. I cannot make any fill methods work for me.

Yes I have spent a couple of days trying different methods and documentations including having a look in three different books on ML!

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pandas as pd
'''
Python version '3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 10:22:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]'
Running Spyder IDE version 3.2.6
PANDAS VERSION '0.22.0'
'''
# Note: missing minute data at 15:28:00 
TS = pd.DataFrame({'recdate': [ '2005-09-28 15:27:00', '2005-09-28 
15:29:00'],
    'outdoortemperature': [12.778, 12.833] })
# Also tested:
# TS['recdate'] = TS['recdate'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
# TS['recdate'] = TS['recdate'].to_datetime()


print("step 1. TS.dtypes: ",TS.dtypes)

TS.set_index(['recdate']) # does not affect the result?
# tested variations - same result:
#TS['recdate'] = TS['recdate'].asfreq('1min')

#TS.index =pd.to_datetime(TS.index)
TS.index =TS.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(TS['recdate']))
TS['recdate'] = TS['recdate'].asfreq('1T')  
print(TS.recdate)


print("step 2. TS.dtypes: ",TS.dtypes)

print(TS)
```

What I thoght was possible would be something like:

```
enter code here
Gives:
       doortemperature recdate
0               12.778     NaT
1               12.833     NaT


Expected something like:
...
     0  12.778   2005-09-28 15:28:00 
     1  NaN      2005-09-28 15:28:00  --- New added datetime?!?
     2  12.778   2005-09-28 15:29:00
...
```

Just this code does much of what I would expect, but line 26(?) with .asfreq(1T'), produces an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert input [(12.778, '2005-09-28 15:27:00')] of type <class 'tuple'> to Timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

I was originally very confused by the documentation of pandas and old sample code. Since things change so fast lots of older sample code will not work. This is not exactly as the sample data I provided originally, but this sample takes my own code a step or two further - with just a few lines.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pandas as pd

# Python version
# '3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 10:22:32) [MSC v.1900 64 
#    bit (AMD64)]'
# Running Spyder IDE version 3.2.6
# PANDAS VERSION '0.22.0'

# Note missing minutes data at around 15:28:00 
TS = pd.DataFrame({'recdate': ['2005-09-28 15:22:00', '2005-09-28 15:23:00',
      '2005-09-28 15:24:00', '2005-09-28 15:25:00', '2005-09-28 15:26:00',
      '2005-09-28 15:29:00', '2005-09-28 15:30:00', '2005-09-28 15:31:00',
      '2005-09-28 15:32:00', '2005-09-28 15:33:00',
      '2005-09-28 15:34:00'],
      'outdoortemperature': [12.611, 12.611, 12.611, 12.611, 12.611, 
                             12.833, 12.833, 12.833, 12.944, 12.944, 12.944]
  })

 #format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
 #TS['recdate'] = pd.to_datetime(TS['recdate'], format=format)
 TS['recdate'] = pd.to_datetime(TS['recdate'])
 TS = TS.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(TS['recdate']))

 print(TS)
 print(TS.dtypes)

 TS = TS.resample('1Min').mean()

 print(TS)
 print(TS.dtypes)

 TS['outdoortemperature'] = TS['outdoortemperature'].interpolate(method = 
                         'spline', order=2 )
 print(TS)
```

The last two steps and print(TS):es will produce the following, which is what I wanted!:

```
                     outdoortemperature
recdate                                
2005-09-28 15:22:00              12.611
2005-09-28 15:23:00              12.611
2005-09-28 15:24:00              12.611
2005-09-28 15:25:00              12.611
2005-09-28 15:26:00              12.611
2005-09-28 15:27:00                 NaN
2005-09-28 15:28:00                 NaN
2005-09-28 15:29:00              12.833
2005-09-28 15:30:00              12.833
2005-09-28 15:31:00              12.833
2005-09-28 15:32:00              12.944
2005-09-28 15:33:00              12.944
2005-09-28 15:34:00              12.944
outdoortemperature    float64
dtype: object
                     outdoortemperature
recdate                                
2005-09-28 15:22:00           12.611000
2005-09-28 15:23:00           12.611000
2005-09-28 15:24:00           12.611000
2005-09-28 15:25:00           12.611000
2005-09-28 15:26:00           12.611000
2005-09-28 15:27:00           12.706501
2005-09-28 15:28:00           12.739543
2005-09-28 15:29:00           12.833000
2005-09-28 15:30:00           12.833000
2005-09-28 15:31:00           12.833000
2005-09-28 15:32:00           12.944000
2005-09-28 15:33:00           12.944000
2005-09-28 15:34:00           12.944000
```

You can easily see the interpolated values in this sample output for their extra
decimal precisions.